# Combine several pictures vertically usig the include_graphics function in r markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to merge three imagaes vertically using the include_graphics function of knitr. 
I tried around using the par() and layout function but I didn't get the result I wanted. The keep being displayed horisontally beside each other.

This is an example that does not work:

```
NameofChunk, out.width="50%%",  fig.cap = "Title", fig.subcap=c("Sub1", "Sub2", "Sub3"), echo = FALSE}

par(mfrow=c(3,1))

knitr::include_graphics("Grafik1.eps")
knitr::include_graphics("Grafik2.eps")
knitr::include_graphics("Grafik3.eps")
```

I am using r bookdown.

My minimal example

Header

```
--- 
title: Title
Subtitle: Subtitle
author:Author
date: "Date"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
classoption: oneside
bibliography: [Doktorarbeit.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
geometry: "left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm"
fontsize: 11pt
linestretch: 1.5
always_allow_html: true
subparagraph: true
---
```

Preable

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\let\origfigure\figure
\let\endorigfigure\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][2] {
    \expandafter\origfigure\expandafter[H]
} {
    \endorigfigure
}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\pagestyle{plain}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[margin = 8pt]{subfig}
```

_Output.yml

```
bookdown::pdf_document2:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  latex_engine: lualatex
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: true
  fig_caption: yes
```

Thanks a lot!!!